# Tic tac toe game switching between X and O

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making a Tic Tac Toe but I am a bit stuck at switching between the cross en circle (as you can see in the var list and the function img.
How do I get this to work?

Javascript code

varcode

```
var vak1 = document.getElementById("vak1");
var vak2 = document.getElementById("vak2");
var vak3 = document.getElementById("vak3");
var vak4 = document.getElementById("vak4");
var vak5 = document.getElementById("vak5");
var vak6 = document.getElementById("vak6");
var vak7 = document.getElementById("vak7");
var vak8 = document.getElementById("vak8");
var vak9 = document.getElementById("vak9");
var circle = "../img/circle.jpg";
var cross = "../img/cross.jpg";
var empty = "../img/empty.jpg";
var Player = document.getElementById("player");
```

first function saying who's turn it is.

```
function player() {
"use strict";
if (Player.innerHTML == 1) {

    Player.innerHTML = 2;
    window.alert("Speler 2 is aan de beurt");
} else {
    Player.innerHTML = 1;
    window.alert("Speler 1 is aan de beurt");
}
}
```

The function that should switch between the x and o image.

```
function img(HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
"use strict";
if (document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).className ===  "leeg") {
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).src = cross;
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).className = "kruis";
    player();
} else {
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).src = circle;
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).className = "rondje";
    player();
}
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<head>
    <title>Boter, Kaas en Eieren</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">

        <h1>Boter, Kaas &amp; Eieren</h1>

        <div id="speelveld">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak1" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak2" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak3" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);"  src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak4" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak5" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak6" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak7" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak8" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                    <td><img class="leeg" id="vak9" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this.id);" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- EINDE SPEELVELD CONTAINER -->

        <div id="game-info">
            <h1>Aan beurt</h1>

            <table class="players-turn" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="25" height="25" alt="" title="" src="img/cross.jpg" /></td>
                    <td>Speler</td>
                    <td id="player">1</td>
                </tr>
            </table> <!-- EINDE SPELER AAN ZET TABEL -->

            <h1>Scores</h1>

            <table class="rounds-info">
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="15" height="15" alt="" title="" src="img/cross.jpg" />&nbsp;Speler 1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="15" height="15" alt="" title="" src="img/circle.jpg" />&nbsp;Speler 2</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Aantal rondes</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </table> <!-- EINDE INFO TABEL -->

            <button class="game-button">Start spel</button>

        </div> <!-- EINDE GAME-INFO CONTAINER -->

    </div> <!-- EINDE MAINCONTAINER -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bke.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo with [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?), of iets anders is ook goed. (or something else)

Comment: What does "switching between" mean? What's not working?

Comment: Ha veel nederlandstaligen hier. You should store what the current image is in a variable, probably best as a `boolean`.

Comment: So *I think* the question you are asking is how to figure out which player clicked a cell so you know whether to turn that into an `X` or an `O`. The answer is that you should have a data structure (an object) that stores the state of your game (including who's turn it is) instead of storing that *in* the HTML, which is a horrible mess. The quick and dirty answer is that you'd have to use the same `Player.innerHTML` you use in the `player` function.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to check what players turn it is in your `img()` function.  This should work:

```
function img(HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
"use strict";

  if(Player.innerHTML == 1) {
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).src = cross;
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).className = "kruis";
    player();
} else {
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).src = circle;
    document.getElementById(HTMLTableDataCellElement).className = "rondje";
    player();
}
}
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5nmmvdt/1/

A more complete solution would be to store the current player as a variable, and not as HTML inside the `<td id="player">` element.  You can also optimize your `img()` function to toggle between kruis en rondje without repeating the same code.  Something like this will work:

```
function img(HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
    "use strict";
    if(HTMLTableDataCellElement.className ==  "leeg") {
        HTMLTableDataCellElement.src = playerData[currentPlayer-1].src;
        HTMLTableDataCellElement.className = playerData[currentPlayer-1].className;
        player();
    }
}

var playerData = [
  {
    src: "cross",
    className: "kruis"},
  {
    src: "circle",
    className: "rondje"}
];

var vak1 = document.getElementById("vak1");
var vak2 = document.getElementById("vak2");
var vak3 = document.getElementById("vak3");
var vak4 = document.getElementById("vak4");
var vak5 = document.getElementById("vak5");
var vak6 = document.getElementById("vak6");
var vak7 = document.getElementById("vak7");
var vak8 = document.getElementById("vak8");
var vak9 = document.getElementById("vak9");
var circle = "../img/circle.jpg";
var cross = "../img/cross.jpg";
var empty = "../img/empty.jpg";
var currentPlayer = 1;


function player() {
    "use strict";
    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == 2) ? currentPlayer = 1 : currentPlayer = 2;

    document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer;
    window.alert("Speler "+currentPlayer+" is aan de beurt");
}
```

You'd also want to clean up the HTML and JS, by only passing the `this` (object reference) instead of the image id (string).  Like this:  `<img class="leeg" id="vak2" alt="" title="" onclick="img(this);" src="img/empty.jpg" />`

I've updated the JS fiddle so you can see how that is working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/j5nmmvdt/3/  Hoop dat het helpt u!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a demo but the problem appears to be that there is, in fact, no switch between the images depending on the player here. After cleaning up a bit your code looks like this:

```
function img(cell_id) {
    "use strict";
    var selCell = document.getElementById(cell_id);
    if (selCell.className ===  "leeg") {
        selCell.src = cross;
        selCell.className = "kruis";
        player();
    } else {
        selCell.src = circle;
        selCell.className = "rondje";
        player();
    }
}
```

What this does, as far as I can see, is:

1. Check if the cell is empty.
2. If yes, place a cross.
3. If no, place a circle.

What you need is:

1. Check if the cell is empty.
2. If no, do nothing.
3. If yes:

   - If it's player 1's turn, place cross.
   - If it's player 2's turn, place circle.

So, something like this:

```
function img(cell_id) {
    "use strict";
    var selCell = document.getElementById(cell_id);
    if (selCell.className ===  "leeg") {
        if (Player.innerHTML == 1) {
            selCell.src = cross;
            selCell.className = "kruis";
        } else {
            selCell.src = circle;
            selCell.className = "rondje";
        }
        player();
    }
}
```

P.S. I replaced "HTMLTableDataCellElement" with "cell_id" as you aren't passing a HTMLTableDataCellElement object to the function. You are, in fact, passing just an id, so it is confusing to call the passed variable HTMLTableDataCellElement.